# arm-eabi-none won't assemble floating point instructions

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, fpu

I am programing for a hardware project. I need an implementation of sin, cos, tan, sqrt, etc. for this project. I do not have any standard libraries available to me for this project, and the results must have floating point retained. Whenever I try to assemble the file (shown below the output), the assembler gives me the error

```
_core_math_arm.s:30: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `fltd f0,r3`
_core_math_arm.s:31: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `sindz f0,f0`
_core_math_arm.s:32: Error: selected processor does not support ARM mode `fix r3 ,f0`
```

I am assembling with `arm-none-eabi-as -o_core_math_arm.bin _core_math_arm.s -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a5 -mfpu=vfpv4 -mfloat=hard`.

All the options match the target processor that I want.

I downloaded this toolchain from https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+download.

The file that is being assembled is as shown below:

```
    .cpu arm7tdmi
    .fpu softvfp
    .eabi_attribute 20, 1
    .eabi_attribute 21, 1
    .eabi_attribute 23, 3
    .eabi_attribute 24, 1
    .eabi_attribute 25, 1
    .eabi_attribute 26, 1
    .eabi_attribute 30, 6
    .eabi_attribute 34, 0
    .eabi_attribute 18, 4
    .file   "core_math.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .global sin
    .type   sin, %function
sin:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    add fp, sp, #4
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [fp, #-12]
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    sub r4, fp, #12
    ldmia   r4, {r3-r4}
@ 6 "core_math.c" 1
    fltd f0, r3 
    sindz f0, f0 
    fix r3, f0
@ 0 "" 2
    str r3, [fp, #-12]
    str r4, [fp, #-8]
    sub r4, fp, #12
    ldmia   r4, {r3-r4}
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #4
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    bx  lr
    .size   sin, .-sin
    .align  2
    .global cos
    .type   cos, %function
cos:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    add fp, sp, #4
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [fp, #-12]
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    sub r4, fp, #12
    ldmia   r4, {r3-r4}
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #4
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    bx  lr
    .size   cos, .-cos
    .align  2
    .global tan
    .type   tan, %function
tan:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    add fp, sp, #4
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [fp, #-12]
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    sub r4, fp, #12
    ldmia   r4, {r3-r4}
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #4
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    bx  lr
    .size   tan, .-tan
    .align  2
    .global csc
    .type   csc, %function
csc:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    add fp, sp, #4
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [fp, #-12]
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    sub r4, fp, #12
    ldmia   r4, {r3-r4}
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #4
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    bx  lr
    .size   csc, .-csc
    .align  2
    .global sec
    .type   sec, %function
sec:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    add fp, sp, #4
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [fp, #-12]
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    sub r4, fp, #12
    ldmia   r4, {r3-r4}
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #4
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    bx  lr
    .size   sec, .-sec
    .align  2
    .global cot
    .type   cot, %function
cot:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    add fp, sp, #4
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [fp, #-12]
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    sub r4, fp, #12
    ldmia   r4, {r3-r4}
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #4
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    bx  lr
    .size   cot, .-cot
    .align  2
    .global sqrt
    .type   sqrt, %function
sqrt:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    add fp, sp, #4
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [fp, #-12]
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    sub r4, fp, #12
    ldmia   r4, {r3-r4}
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #4
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    bx  lr
    .size   sqrt, .-sqrt
    .align  2
    .global invsqrt
    .type   invsqrt, %function
invsqrt:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    add fp, sp, #4
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [fp, #-12]
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    sub r4, fp, #12
    ldmia   r4, {r3-r4}
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #4
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    bx  lr
    .size   invsqrt, .-invsqrt
    .global __aeabi_dadd
    .align  2
    .global pow
    .type   pow, %function
pow:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 16
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp, lr}
    add fp, sp, #8
    sub sp, sp, #20
    str r0, [fp, #-20]
    str r1, [fp, #-16]
    str r2, [fp, #-28]
    str r3, [fp, #-24]
    sub r1, fp, #20
    ldmia   r1, {r0-r1}
    sub r3, fp, #28
    ldmia   r3, {r2-r3}
    bl  __aeabi_dadd
    mov r3, r0
    mov r4, r1
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #8
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp, lr}
    bx  lr
    .size   pow, .-pow
    .align  2
    .global ln
    .type   ln, %function
ln:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    add fp, sp, #4
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [fp, #-12]
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    sub r4, fp, #12
    ldmia   r4, {r3-r4}
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #4
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    bx  lr
    .size   ln, .-ln
    .align  2
    .global log10
    .type   log10, %function
log10:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    @ link register save eliminated.
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    add fp, sp, #4
    sub sp, sp, #8
    str r0, [fp, #-12]
    str r1, [fp, #-8]
    sub r4, fp, #12
    ldmia   r4, {r3-r4}
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #4
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp}
    bx  lr
    .size   log10, .-log10
    .align  2
    .global logn
    .type   logn, %function
logn:
    @ Function supports interworking.
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 16
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    stmfd   sp!, {r4, fp, lr}
    add fp, sp, #8
    sub sp, sp, #20
    str r0, [fp, #-20]
    str r1, [fp, #-16]
    str r2, [fp, #-28]
    str r3, [fp, #-24]
    sub r1, fp, #20
    ldmia   r1, {r0-r1}
    sub r3, fp, #28
    ldmia   r3, {r2-r3}
    bl  __aeabi_dadd
    mov r3, r0
    mov r4, r1
    mov r0, r3
    mov r1, r4
    sub sp, fp, #8
    @ sp needed
    ldmfd   sp!, {r4, fp, lr}
    bx  lr
    .size   logn, .-logn
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 4.9.3 20141119 (release) [ARM/embedded-4_9-branch revision 218278]"
```

This file IS generated by a `-S` option to `arm-none-gcc`.

The instructions seem to not be able to be recognized 100% properly by the assembler to be fpu instructions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do _all_ the options _really_ match? What do the first two lines of that listing say? (hint: directives trump command-line options)

Comment: @Notlikethat datasheet can be found here: http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-11121-32-bit-Cortex-A5-Microcontroller_SAMA5D3_Datasheet.pdf

Comment: @Notlikethat if the fpu instructions are not supported, just say that this processor doesn't support fpu instructions.

Comment: My point is that Cortex-A5 with [VFP](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473k/dom1361289932816.html) is not an ARM7TDMI with the ancient legacy [Floating-Point Accelerator](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0041c/BIHBJIEA.html). You have a fundamental mismatch there.

Comment: @Notlikethat How do I use floating point instructions then?

Comment: Er, you use the floating-point instructions that _your_ FPU supports, not the ones that _some other FPU_ supports. The code here is targeted at something very different to your hardware, and the error message is telling you exactly that.